# There is limit on google cloud projects and firebase projects?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I build websites, maybe 100 per year maybe more and I start to use Firebase and Google cloud for my hosting and as a backend but after some projects on blade for firebase I am not able to create new projects.

I make project quota to increase my projects but I don't have any response

My point is there is any alternative for hosting angular 2 apps with node.js 
backend

Answer (score 2):

There are lot more of hosting options available on google cloud than only firebase.
[Google App Engine(Standard)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) is one of them. They even give you a predefined run time environment. If you want to use node.js in the background you just have to mention node as your runtime environment in the application configuration file.

Then there is [Google App Engine(flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/)

If you want to create your own virtual machine and create your own servers you can choose [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)